# Shuffle column in panda dataframe with groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I want to randomly shuffle the values for one single column of a dataframe based on a groupby. E.g., I have two columns A and B. Now, I want to randomly shuffle column B based on a groupby on A.

For an example, suppose that there are three distinct values in A. Now for each distinct value of A, I want to shuffle the values in B, but just with values having the same A.

Example input:

```
A       B     
------------
1       1          
1       3    
2       4     
3       6   
1       2  
3       5
```

Example output:

```
A       B        
------------
1       3          
1       2    
2       4     
3       6   
1       1  
3       5
```

In this case, for `A=1` the values for B got shuffled. The same happened for `A=2`, but as there is only one row it stayed like it was. For `A=3` by chance the values for B also stayed like they were.

I want to achieve it with Pandas.

Comment: Could you please provide sample data and expected output? [ask]

Comment: Sure, provided an example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For this you could combine `np.random.permutation` (which returns a shuffled version of an array) with a `groupby` and a `transform` (which returns a like-indexed version of the group).  For example:

```
>>> df
   col1  col2
0     1     1
1     1     3
2     2     4
3     3     6
4     1     2
5     3     5
>>> df["col3"] = df.groupby("col1")["col2"].transform(np.random.permutation)
>>> df
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     1     2
1     1     3     1
2     2     4     4
3     3     6     5
4     1     2     3
5     3     5     6
```

Note that the values are only shuffled within their col1 groups.

Comment: That's it. I was actually so close to your solution :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `groupby` together with `sample`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3], 
                   'col2': [1, 3, 4, 6, 2, 5]})

df_rand = df.groupby('col1').apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=1)).reset_index(drop=True)

>>> df.sort('col1')
   col1  col2
0     1     1
1     1     3
4     1     2
2     2     4
3     3     6
5     3     5

>>> df_rand
   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     1     3
2     1     1
3     2     4
4     3     6
5     3     5
```

Comment: Would this work with multiple columns though if you only want to shuffle one?