# Identical shuffling of pandas dataframe column after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, shuffle

I have a dataframe with the following structure

```
ID  col2    col3
1   101001  a
1   101001  b
1   101001  c
1   101002  a
1   101002  b
1   101002  c
1   101003  a
1   101003  b
1   101003  c
1   101004  a
1   101004  b
1   101004  c
2   101001  a
2   101001  b
2   101001  d
2   101002  a
2   101002  b
2   101002  d
2   101003  a
2   101003  b
2   101003  d
2   101004  a
2   101004  b
2   101004  d
3   101001  b
3   101001  c
3   101001  d
3   101002  b
3   101002  c
3   101002  d
3   101003  b
3   101003  c
3   101003  d
3   101004  b
3   101004  c
3   101004  d
```

I need to group by column `ID`, reshuffle the entries in column `col3` for each respective `ID` and write the results in a new column `col4`. In addition the shuffling should be identical for a given `ID`, independent of the entries in `col2`, e.g. for `ID=1` the entry `a` in `col3` should always be `b` after reshuffling:

```
ID  col2    col3    col4
1   101001  a   b
1   101001  b   a
1   101001  c   c
1   101002  a   b
1   101002  b   a
1   101002  c   c
1   101003  a   b
1   101003  b   a
1   101003  c   c
1   101004  a   b
1   101004  b   a
1   101004  c   c
2   101001  a   d
2   101001  b   a
2   101001  d   b
2   101002  a   d
2   101002  b   a
2   101002  d   b
2   101003  a   d
2   101003  b   a
2   101003  d   b
2   101004  a   d
2   101004  b   a
2   101004  d   b
3   101001  b   b
3   101001  c   d
3   101001  d   c
3   101002  b   b
3   101002  c   d
3   101002  d   c
3   101003  b   b
3   101003  c   d
3   101003  d   c
3   101004  b   b
3   101004  c   d
3   101004  d   c
```

Following [Shuffle column in panda dataframe with groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662821/shuffle-column-in-panda-dataframe-with-groupby) using `df['col4'] = test_df.groupby('ID')['col3'].transform(np.random.permutation)` does not work in my case since the shuffled results vary within a given `ID`, due to the varying entries in `col2`.

Comment: "e.g. for `ID=1` the entry `a` in `col3` should always be `b` after reshuffling" why not `c`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @TobiasMolenaar Sure, it could also be `c` or `d`, as long it is consistent for a given `ID`. So, `a` could also be `c` for `ID=1`, but `b` for `ID=2` and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from random import sample

def f(ser):
    elements = list(set(ser))
    replacements = sample(elements, len(elements))
    return ser.replace(elements, replacements)

df['col3'] = df.groupby('ID')['col2'].transform(f)
```

**Example:**

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                   'col2': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'f', 'a', 'f']})
```

Result:

```py
   ID col2 col3
0   1    a    a
1   1    b    c
2   1    a    a
3   1    c    b
4   1    b    c
5   2    a    f
6   2    f    a
7   2    a    f
8   2    f    a
```